# Vaadin connect DB as grid backend

Tags: java, postgresql, vaadin

This [tutorial](https://github.com/vaadin/tutorial/) is very specific and I'm experimenting with it but there I got stuck. My target is to make all changes in UI save in PostgreSQL.

So, in order to do it, i'm using [Vaadin SQLContainer](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/sqlcontainer/sqlcontainer-architecture.html) ans have setup it as are datasource for the grid (see tutorial mentioned before) and grid actually get filled with data from the PostgreSQL.

The problem starts when i have to edit Listeners that are responsible for editing. They all are coded for work with a class not SQLContainer.

Listener code example:

```
 grid.addSelectionListener(event - > {
     if (event.getSelected().isEmpty()) {
         form.setVisible(false);
     } else {
         Customer customer = (Customer)
         event.getSelected().iterator().next();
         form.setCustomer(customer);
     }
 });
```

Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.RowId cannot be cast to ua.bdproject.nameproject.Customer
```

Comment: I guess you need to read the entity by "RowId" from DB first before you can edit it. The selection of the `Grid` is the item IDs, see [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html#components.grid.selection.single).